# How do I prove that $\sin(π/2+iy)=1/2(e^{y}+e^{−y})=\cosh y$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

How do I prove that $\sin(π/2+iy)=1/2(e^{y}+e^{−y})=\cosh y$?

Can you help please?

Comment: Are you familiar with Euler's formula?

Comment: It might surprise you to find that the addition formula for $\sin$ works for complex arguments as well... use that, along with $\sin\,ix=i\sinh\,x$ and $\cos\,ix=\cosh\,x$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments helped me a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_cosine#Standard_algebraic_expressions) of $\cosh(y)$ is 
$$\cosh(y)=\frac{e^y+e^{-y}}{2}.$$
[The definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Sine_with_a_complex_argument) of $\sin(z)$ (or [a property, if you use some other definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry)) is
$$\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}.$$
Thus
$$\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{2}+iy)=\frac{e^{i\left(\tfrac{\pi}{2}+iy\right)}-e^{-i\left(\tfrac{\pi}{2}+iy\right)}}{2i}=\frac{e^{\pi i/2}e^{-y}-e^{-\pi i/2}e^y}{2i}.$$
Now consider what $e^{\pi i/2}$ is, and you will be done.

Comment: This is equal to i and with this result is obtained